# Performing an operation days or months in the future

Tags: javascript, email, meteor, futuretask

I'm trying to figure out the best way to perform a task, e.g. send an email to a user, in the future.

My idea is to store (in a database along with users data) when the email needs to be sent, and on a daily basis check what users need emails sent, and use Meteor's Timer functions.

```
// 7 hours in millisec.
Meteor.setTimeout( function() {
    Meteor.call( "sendReminderEmail", ... );
}, 2.52e+7 );
```

The problem that I see is having too many timers set up, and hindering performance. What is a good solution?

**Edit:** Basically my use case includes the user creating an event, which they set as a long term event or short term(based on days, weeks, or months), and they receive a follow-up on that event depending on the duration.

I guess I could check every hour, but that seems like a problem with equal cost. Is there a Meteor specific way to do this? Or just a better concept?

**Edit2:** Ok, I've realized that accurracy isn't that important for my problem, so I'm thinking of setting one timer per timezone, which would send bulk emails. If the user has a long term event and their reminder is this week, than send it now. Basically it depends on duration of event and timezone of user.

**So my updated question is, how do I run something on a daily basis, with my problem in mind?**

Comment: If you're checking on a daily basis, why do you use that 7 hour timeout?

Comment: do less mails more often???

Comment: @ŠimeVidas it's 7 hours from the start of the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to execute a code at 9am today and now is 8am, you could create a timeout to match the minutes in the targeted time and then create a interval of 1 hour and at each execution check if the time is 9am, if it's, execute.

in this small scale example, I'm executing `executeMe()` when the clock shows 9 seconds:

Live Test: http://jsbin.com/ikulok/4/edit

```
<body>
Last run: <span id="time"></span><br>
Next execution: <span id="target"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function executeMe(){
      alert("9 seconds!");
    }
    var timeout = null;
    var interval = null;
    function timer(){
      var now = new Date();
      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = now;
      document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = new Date(now.getTime()+ 1000);
      //console.log("timer()", now);

      if(now.getSeconds() == 9)
        setTimeout("executeMe();",1); // async

      if(interval == null)
        interval = setInterval("timer()",1000);
    }

    var now = new Date();
    var target = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate(),now.getHours(),now.getMinutes(),now.getSeconds()+1,0);
    //console.log("now", now);
    //console.log("target", target);
    //console.log("diff", target.getTime() - now.getTime());
    document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = target;
    timeout = setTimeout("timer()", target.getTime() - now.getTime() );
  </script>
```

---

If you want to run the `timer()` every hour instead of every second, just adjust the `target` and the `setInterval()` and of course your conditions

Live Test: http://jsbin.com/ikulok/3/edit

```
<body>
  Last run: <span id="time"></span><br>
  Next execution: <span id="target"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function executeMe(){
      alert("1:20am!");
    }
    var timeout = null;
    var interval = null;
    function timer(){
      var now = new Date();
      document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = now;
      document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = new Date(now.getTime()+ 1*60*60*1000);
      //console.log("timer()", now);

      if(now.getHour() == 1)
        setTimeout("executeMe();", 20*60*1000); // !!!! this will execute at 1:20am

      if(interval == null)
        interval = setInterval("timer()",1*60*60*1000); // !!!! repeat every hour
    }

    var now = new Date();

    // !!!! targeting next exact hour
    var target = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate(),now.getHours(),now.getMinutes()+1,0,0);
    //console.log("now", now);
    //console.log("target", target);
    //console.log("diff", target.getTime() - now.getTime());
    document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = target;
    timeout = setTimeout("timer()", target.getTime() - now.getTime() );
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: @Knownasilya I've edited to show you an example of how to execute a function every 1:20am, of course you can add more conditions to it, take as an example

Comment: @Knownasilya I fixed some errors with the Date object in both examples provided